# Whole entity instance as argument or its id

Tags: jpa

I would like to persist the entity `InterviewFeedback`. `InterviewGuide` and `Application` are other entities. Should I pass as argument the whole entity instance (e.g., `Application`), or just the id of the entity and then make a query to find the instance by its id? What will be the problems passing the whole entity instance as argument?

```
public void createInterview(Date interviewDate, Interviewer interviewer, InterviewGuide interviewGuide, Application application) {
        InterviewFeedback interviewFeedback = new InterviewFeedback();
        interviewFeedback.setInterviewer(interviewer);
        interviewFeedback.setInterviewDate(interviewDate);
        interviewFeedback.setInterviewGuide(interviewGuide);
        if (knowIfInterviewHasPhoneInterviewGuide(InterviewType.PHONE, application)) {
            interviewFeedback.setInterviewType(InterviewType.PHONE);

        } else {
            interviewFeedback.setInterviewType(InterviewType.PRESENCIAL);
        }
        interviewFeedback.setApplication(application);
        em.persist(interviewFeedback);

    }
```

Comment: Truth is you could do both, the only issue passing the instance is you might have to deal with detached entities. It's hard to give you a definitive answer without seeing how this method is called in context of your app and also taking into account transactional boundaries etc.